# Nymph's Kiss and the Relationship

Tags: dnd-3.5e

So we are playing D&D 3.5 and I thought about taking the Feat "Nymph's Kiss" from Book of Exalted Deeds (and tell my DM about it so he could make it happen).
The problem now is the following:

> By maintaining an intimate relationship with a good-aligned fey...

My question is what happens if the relationship is broken for whatever reason? Let's assume the fey dies, or if it's a nymph like the Feat title suggests and the PC wants/has to travel and the nymph can't leave her pond behind to travel with her lover, what happens then with this feat? Does the PC lose all benefits? Or is it just necessary to meet the fey every now and then to "charge the battery" so to speak? Is there any official answer to this? I took a look into the errata of the Book of Exalted Deeds but there was nothing to find.

Comment: It's important to remember that the intimate relationship is mentioned under the **benefits** of the feat. ;)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

## Confirm the Fluff with the DM

The only thing important about the exalted feat Nymph's Kiss (*BE* 44) is what it is (an exalted feat) and what it does (the feat's Benefit). Everything *else* about that feat is purely descriptive. The *Player's Handbook* says

> Some feats have prerequisites. Your character must have the indicated ability score, class feature, feat, skill, base attack bonus, or other quality designated in order to select or use that feat. ... A character can’t use a feat if he or she has lost a prerequisite. (87)

The feat Nymph's Kiss has no prerequisites.

The DM can always house rule prerequisites for the feat, but if he doesn't, once the player's received the DM's permission and the player's character has taken the feat, the feat's there. Only if the character commits an evil act or is "in areas where magic is suppressed or negated (such as an *antimagic field*)" (*PH* 180) does the feat disappear.

#### Evil Acts

As the feat Nymph's Kiss is an exalted feat,

> A character who willingly and willfully commits an evil act loses all benefits from all his exalted feats. She regains these benefits if she atones for her violations.... (*BE* 39)

Thus, if the character were "trying to dupe someone into buying a cursed item" (*DMG* 277), which is an evil act, all the character's exalted feats' benefits would be lost until he atoned.

#### Areas of Suppressed or Negated Magic

Strangely, a character loses all exalted *feats* in areas where magic doesn't function:

> These [exalted] feats are... supernatural in nature (rather than being extraordinary abilities, as most feats are). (*BE* 39)

Luckily, the character with the feat Nymph's Kiss probably spent the skill points he gained, so he needn't subtract those when he enters such an area, but it's something to keep in mind if those feats are prerequisites.

---

## Really, Talk to the DM

The DM *must* approve the feat, and he must be on board with your character taking a feat that mandates your character be *good* or lose the feat. If the DM's used to putting devastating moral quandaries in front of the characters, forcing them to constantly choose the lesser of several evils, the character will be hard to play and might not fit the campaign. That's a thing. Talk to the DM. Absolutely.

But only the DM can house rule that your character must *do something* to keep his feat. That's his call... even if the feat has no prerequisites.

Answer (score 12):

Like a lot of things from the BoED, the rules for what constitutes a relationship are not great, and very up to interpretation.  This sort of thing is going to be almost entirely up to your GM.  Your GM might be totally cool with the 'pining lover' idea, where you go off to adventure and only come back every few months or years to be with your fey lover again.  Your GM might require visits more often than that.  Personally, I would say that as long as you made reasonable attempts to get back to your fey lover when you had the chance, I'd let you keep the feat.

Once your relationship is over (however it happens), the rules are pretty clear.  If you no longer meet the requirements for a feat, you lose access to the benefits of that feat until you meet the requirements again.  It's going to be between you and your GM what happens to your bonus skill points if/when that happens.

As an aside, I'd *very* strongly suggest that you stay away from the BoED.  It's a very poorly written book, with a lot of things in it that are either extremely weak or extremely powerful that aren't terribly obvious, and there are several options that either don't make sense on the face of it or break campaigns entirely.  You'd be a lot better off working with your GM to make your own good-aligned character options than you'd be using that book.

As other answerers have pointed out, the line that you reference is in the fluff of the feat, and is not listed as a prerequisite.  Technically, by the RAW, any exalted character can take this feat whether they have ever met a Fey creature or not, since there is no spelled out prerequisite about your contact with a Fey, only fluff.  This is yet another example of the extremely poor writing and editing in this book, and should give you more of an idea of what you're getting into by using BoED content.

Answer (score 3):

This is a rather interesting question, especially considering the fluff being written into the feat description without being written as a prerequisite.

If you were in my game and the relationship with the good aligned Fey was broken, I would rule that you would lose access to the feat until you were able to complete a quest to lay the Fey's spirit to rest, a.k.a. Fulfill her final request.

Once you're done so you receive a necklace (See: Quest reward) which can use Lesser Planar Ally 1/Day to summon the ghost of the Fey ( and only the ghost ) from the afterlife to assist you in a task, provide knowledge, or just as a companion. This would be considered "maintaining an intimate relationship", as you're able to regularly communicate with either the ghost or physical form of the Fey in her death.

Another route that you could take would be Atonement. Your character realizes that he had a hand in being unable to stop the events which led to the Fey's death, and suffers guilt from not being able to do anything to save her. So he completes a quest, gains the effects of Atonement ( As if he had the spell cast on himself ) And the ghost of the Fey appears, forgives him for what happened, and he regains the use of the feat.

If the relationship was willingly broken due to mutual agreement I'd guess you would lose access to the benefits the feat provided and be able to choose another feat at your next level or until you found another Fey to form another relationship with, but in the end this is really something you're *definitely* going to have to go through your DM. He may want to bring others in the group into this quest of yours and turn it into a big thing.